Python Discord bot problem with editing users who are not in the voice channel
I have a problem with the fact that I can only access users who are in a voice channel. except with the user ID. I have very little knowledge of python myself and am just learning it this code is written using AI. my bot has admin rights.
async def search_user(guild, search_term):
    """Searches for a user in the guild using username, display name, or ID."""
    results = []
    for member in guild.members:
        if search_term.lower() in member.name.lower() or search_term.lower() in member.display_name.lower():
            results.append(member)
    try:
        return guild.get_member(int(search_term))
    except ValueError:
        if not results:
            return None
        if len(results) == 1:
            return results[0]
        raise ValueError(f"Multiple users found matching '{search_term}': {', '.join([member.name for member in results])}")


What is your question? Did you see [ask]?
